# Cheap bandwidth to Google apps (Dynamics E-mail Router hosting)

Tags: bandwidth, g-suite

To give a bit of context, we are looking to host our Microsoft dynamics e-mail router to connect to Google apps e-amil.

We are looking at many options from varying angles, but one possible option is looking at a cloud VM, however it occurred to me is the cost of bandwidth.... Ignoring the other options at the moment, this is just for arguments sake:

Is there a way in which to setup a cloud environment to have near-free bandwidth to gmail?
I'm thinking perhaps a tunnel to a specific IP or perhaps hosting in Google Cloud Compute engine (I release GCCE probably isn't an options as I think they only support Linux).

My thoughts behind this are similar to how DB providers operate (e.g. mongolab.com) at the moment by having their database platform installed in your cloud provider to get it closer to the app server.

Answer (score 1):

Cost wise, the best option would be to host your MS Dynamics at a Data Center which is geographically closest to a Google's. For that, you might want to explore AWS, which offers to select where you want to host your VM.

However, I argue the basic principal. Here's an alternative:

1. Setup a Google Apps account.
2. Point your MX records to Google.
3. Configure Google Apps for Dual Delivery to your MS dynamics email router. That will have a copy of all incoming email messages delivered to it.
4. If you would like to go for granularity, you can configure Google Apps's built in email router, to deliver specific messages to your MS dynamics email router.

Comment: That's an interesting idea using dual delivery. But won't AWS bandwidth only be cheaper when it's actually in the same data centre?

Comment: Yet, it will. However, Google doesn't charge you for network bandwidth at all.